# simple linked list implementation logical error?

Tags: c, linked-list

I have implemented a linked list code, but it seems that there is somewhere a logic error in my code, can anyone help me to fix this problem?

```
struct Node{
  int val;
  struct Node *next;
};
void add(struct Node *new_node, struct Node *head){
 struct Node *new_n;
 if( head == NULL){
  head = new_node;
 }
 else{
  new_n = head;
  while(new_n){
    new_n =  new_n->next;
  }
  new_n = new_node;
 }
}
void print(struct Node*n){
  while(n != NULL){
   fprintf(stderr, "val:%d addr%p \t next%p\n",n->val, n, n->next);
   n=n->next;
  } 
}

void main (){
 struct Node *head;
 struct Node *node;
 int i ;
 for( i =1; i< 5; i++){
   struct Node *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
   bzero(node,sizeof(*node));
   node->val = i;
   node->next =NULL;
   add(node, head);  
 }
 print(head);
}
```

This code doesn't print any values? What are the problems with this code?
[ I used: $gcc filename.c -o  filename.o]

Comment: The first problem is `void main()`.

Comment: I suggest you do a search for *emulating pass by reference in c*.

Comment: @n.m. What is the problem with void main()?

Comment: The second problem is that you are running an incorrect compilation command. The correct one would be *gcc **-Wall -Werror** filename.c -o filename.o*

Comment: @MosMoh It's the wrong signature for `main()`, which should always return `int` and take either no parameters (`int main(void)`) or an integer and a string array (`int main(int argc, char *argv[])`). You can't make up your own signature.

Comment: Also remember that local variables (like e.g. `head` inside the `main` function) are ***not initialized***. An uninitialized local variable will have an *indeterminate* value.

Comment: The third problem is that you never initialise or assign or change `head` in any way, so you cannot expect it to contain anything in particular.

Comment: another (minor and unrelated) problem, is that bzero is deprecated : http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/bzero.3.html since POSIX.1-2001

Comment: @n.m  I did what you suggested, but the problem still exists, I make int main(void), compiled with: gcc -Wall -Werror filename.c -o filename.o, and made an initialization for head pointer= NULL;

Comment: Side note: even if your code worked, it is very inefficient, because each time you add a node to the list you iterate over all elements in order to find the last element. You need to maintain a pointer to the last element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three problems:

1) `head` is never initialized

Use:

```
struct Node *head = NULL;
```

2) Changes to `head` inside the `add` function does **not** change `head` in `main`

Try

```
void add(struct Node *new_node, struct Node **head){
                                           ^^
```

and use `*head` in the function and call it like `add(node, &head);`

3) New elements are not added to the list.

Try:

```
void add(struct Node *new_node, struct Node **head) {
  struct Node *new_n;
  if (*head == NULL) {
    *head = new_node;
  }
  else {
    new_n = *head;
    while (new_n->next) {         // Notice - iterate until the next pointer is NULL
      new_n = new_n->next;
    }
    new_n->next = new_node;     // Notice
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem still exists with me.

Comment: Yes, Thanks, now it works with me, the third item in the given solution is the major mistake I made.

Comment: @MosMoh be aware that this code is still awkward for multiple reasons, even if it works correctly.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, can you illustrate the weak points in it, so I can use it safely in other codes?

Comment: @MosMoh There are several issues: 1: it's inefficient as already mentioned in one of my previous comments. 2. The `add` function should be self contained, e.g. the initialisation of the new node should be done entirely in the `add` function. 3. You should not maintain simply the head but have a structrure e.g. `struct LinkedList {struct node *head; struct node *tail; int size}`.

Answer (score 0):

in doing this you return a pointer to the new head node and thus can iterate the new list containing your newer element at the end of the list.

```
struct Node{
      int val;
      struct Node *next;
};

*Node add(struct Node *new_node, struct Node *head)
{
 struct Node *new_n;
 if( head == NULL)
 {
  head = new_node;
 }
 else
 {
  new_n = head;
  while(new_n)
  {
    new_n =  new_n->next;
  }
  new_n = new_node;
 }
return new_n;
}

void print(struct Node*n){
  while(n != NULL){
   fprintf(stderr, "val:%d addr%p \t next%p\n",n->val, n, n->next);
   n=n->next;
  } 
}

void main (){
 struct Node *head;
 struct Node *node;
 int i ;
 for( i =1; i< 5; i++){
   struct Node *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
   bzero(node,sizeof(*node));
   node->val = i;
   node->next =NULL;
   *head = add(node, head); 

}
 print(head);
}
```